# Moving an input[type=file] into a different form, before submitting

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, post, iframe

I'm trying to do an IFrame file/form submit to emulate an Ajax file upload post for IE9.

The input element is originally in the middle of my ASPX form (i.e `runat=server` etc), because it's outputted in a `ASP:Repeater` control.

When the user clicks the Submit button, I dynamically create a form outside the web form, plus an IFrame, and then move the file input into the new form, then submit the form.

The IFrame posts up to my .ASPX page where I can extract the form elements, except the copied file input element is not present.

Is there something that prevents you from moving a file input element?

This is the code that creates the form and moves the file element:

```
$("body").append("<form id='addedForm'></form>");
var addedForm = document.getElementById('addedForm');
addedForm.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
addedForm.setAttribute("action", rootUrl + "evaluationprefileupload.aspx");
addedForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
addedForm.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
addedForm.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
$("#addedForm").append($("#FileName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was this:

`<input type="file" id="FileName" class="form-control" />`

There was no `name` attribute.